# how to create a three dimensional dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, new-operator

I wanted to create a three dimensional array in the following code but i get run time error.

```
int dim1,dim2,dim3;
std::cout<<"dim one\n";
std::cin>>dim1;
std::cout<<"dim two\n";
std::cin>>dim2;
std::cout<<"dim three\n";
std::cin>>dim3;

int ***three_dim=0;
three_dim=new int**[dim1];
for(int i=0;i<dim1;++i)
    three_dim[i]=new int*[dim2];

for(int k=0;k<dim2;++k)
    three_dim[k]=new int*[dim3];
for(int k=0;k<dim1;++k)
for(int i=0;i<dim2;++i)
    for(int j=0;j<dim3;++j)
        three_dim[k][i][j]=0;
```

EDIT:

it is a must that i use a three dimensional array. I have created a two dimensional array with the same style and wanted to extend it to three because that is what i need. But as you can see i got confused.

Thank you **Bo Persson**

Comment: a) Wrap a one dimensional array in a class and do indices-math yourself b) Use a vector of vectors of vectors of ints c) Use boost::multi_array. Just don't do what you're doing right now.

Comment: Any time you're writing `***` and it's not a comment, alarm bells should go off in your mind.

Comment: Yes, the [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part

```
for(int k=0;k<dim2;++k)
    three_dim[k]=new int*[dim3];
```

has two problems. One is that is allocates `int*` instead of `int`. The other, more serious, is that it overwrites the previously allocated pointers from the lines above.

You should probably do the allocation like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<dim1;++i)
{
    three_dim[i]=new int*[dim2];

    for(int k=0;k<dim2;++k)
        three_dim[i][k]=new int[dim3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this kind of thing with pointers will just get you in the end.

One easier way of doing it, if you really need a three dimensional array, is to use nested STL containers. I.e. `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>`.

Make sure that you're solving the right problem. I'm not saying you're not, but I just get a gut feeling you might be able to solve it without a three dimensional array, which can be a beast to handle, especially if you're not comfortable with pointers.